# Induction: Show: $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{5}{6} \times ... \times \frac{2n-1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

**The question:**

Show by using induction that: $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{5}{6} \times ... \times \frac{2n-1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ for all $n$ $\in$ $Z_+$

**My attempt at a solution:**

first of we check the base case $n = 1$:

This gives us: $\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3+1}} = \frac{1}{2}$ The base case works.

Now we assume that the statement is true for some $k = n$.

Then we have to prove that it also holds true for $k = n+1$.

This gives us:

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} \times ... \times \frac{2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$$

If we then can prove that this holds true: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}} \times \frac{2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$ we have proven the that it holds true for all $n$ in $Z_+$

We start by writing the expression like this:

$$\frac{2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)} \leq \frac{\sqrt{3n+1}}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$$

$(1):$

$$\frac{2(n+1)-1}{} \leq \frac{2(n+1)\sqrt{3n+1}}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$$

$(2):$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}(2(n+1)-1)}{} \leq \frac{2(n+1)\sqrt{3n+1}}{}$$

$(3):$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3n+4}(2n+1)}{} \leq \frac{(2n+2)\sqrt{3n+1}}{}$$

Please help me with how I continue from here? Have I had the wrong approach to this problem?

Thank you!